# add_ci() for row percentages, gtsummary and tbl_svysummary

Tags: r, survey, confidence-interval, gtsummary

I am working with weighted survey data and trying to run tables with **row** percentages AND **row** confidence intervals (with `tbl_svysummary`).

I notice that the following output reports row percents for the proportion, but then it reports the confidence intervals for ***column*** percentages.

```
data %>%
   tbl_svysummary(by = "cig",
                  include = ses,
                  percents = "row") %>% 
  add_ci()
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to modify this code to run confidence intervals on the ***row percentages***, not column percentages?

Comment: Ahh, that is not currently possible in gtsummary. Please post an issue to the gtsummary GitHub page to request this feature