# How to obtain the same results using the survey::svyby() function with the svymean argument and the gtsummary::tbl_svysummary function?

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

I would like to reproduce the same result as svyby, with the svymean argument, with the tbl_svysummary() function. It is possible? I tried using the argument #statistic = (all_categorical() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"). But it did not work. Any help?

```
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)

data(api)
dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

svyby(~both, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)

dclus1 %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(by = both,  
                            include =  stype, 
                            #statistic = (all_categorical() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")
                            )
```

The result of svyby is:

[image]

I tried using the argument `statistic = (all_categorical() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")`, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you update your post including code/output using `svyby()` that you want to replicate? I am not sure what you have in mind. My first guess is that you should change `all_categorical()` to `all_continuous()` because only continuous variables should be summarized with means and standard deviations.

Comment: Yes, for sure! Thanks in advance for your interest. I ended up figuring out the answer and will post it below.

Comment: But, now, I have a new problem, as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186902/add-ci-for-row-percentages-gtsummary-and-tbl-svysummary. If that were possible, the result would be the same as ```svyby(~both, ~stype, dclus1, svymean, vartype = c("ci"))```. Would you have any tips, @DanielD.Sjoberg or does the answer remain the same as at the link? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same result on the rows, just like the svyby function, I used the argument {percent = "row"} and {statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}"}, as the following:

```
dclus1 %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(by = both,  
                            include =  stype, 
                            percent = "row",
                            digits = list(stype ~ 1),
                            statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}")
```

The only difference is that in svyby the values are in proportion and with the tbl_svysummary function it is in percentage. Also I don't have de se (stardart error) columns, but that is ok. The result was:

[image]